# R - Using doParallel and lockBinding to write and read the same file from different cores

Tags: r, locking, doparallel

I want to run in parallel a set of functions that I have declared in the clusterEvalQ. Within these functions there is a recursive function that reads from a file and writes the data into it again.

I want to use lockBinding and unlockBinding to avoid multiple tasks over the same file (i.e. if it is writing in it do not read and the other way around).

At the moment, the structure of my code is:

```
check_bind <- function(sym, env) {
    if (bindingIsLocked(sym, env))  {
    Sys.sleep(0.001)
    check_bind(sym, env) } else {
    return(TRUE)
  }


e <- new.env()
foreach () %dopar {
    [code]
    if (!exist(var)){ var <- fread(varfile)
      } else { 
      check_bind("var", e) 
      var <- fread(varfile)}

    [code]

    assign("var", var, e)

    if (check_bind("var", e)) {
    lockBinding("var", e)
    write.table(var, varfile, append=TRUE)
    unlockBinding("var",e)}

   [code]
```

Thus, the code works for several tasks with 4 cores (until 85 tasks) but it always fails, saying that it can not read the file 'cause format is not appropiate but the real question is that it hasn't finished writting.

How can I impose, don't Read until you finish Writing?

Thank you all!,
Karen